# How to avoid spaces after figure

Tags: vertical-alignment

Im trying to make the rules equally spaced

```
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{.6pt}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \rule{0.5cm}{0.5cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{.6pt}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Do you really need `figure`?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a low level primitive, namely `\hrule`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\hrule height 0.6pt

\vspace{1cm}

\rule{0.5cm}{0.5cm}

\vspace{1cm}

\hrule height 0.6pt
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry for the low accuracy, but that's all Adobe Reader provides.

Comment: `texdef` does not work on `\hrule`. How to see its definition?

Comment: @Sigur `\hrule` is a TeX primitive.

Comment: But is it possible to understand better what it is? I mean, how it was defined, constructed, or some other method related to it. For example, how to make it to produce a line?

Comment: @Sigur Look in the TeXbook or in TeX by topic

Answer (score 1):

Also possible with tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) -- ++(\linewidth,0)
      (0,-2) -- ++(\linewidth,0);
\node [draw,fill,minimum size=.5cm] at (\linewidth/2,-1){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]